Nic with 4 ports. Netplan setup?





Summary of the Problem


Summary of the problem:
Ethernet into the apartment. I receive 4 public IPs from the ISP.
Ethernet into the switch, four cables out of the switch.
From the switch, cables go:

Router with he.net 6in4 IPV6 tunnel.. That Router to Port 1 on Ubuntu server
Port 2 on Ubuntu Server
Port 3 on Ubuntu Server
Port 4 on Ubuntu Server

So, the Ubuntu server has a network card with 4 ports. These 4 ports have different MAC addresses.
If I only connect the cable from the router with the IPv6 tunnel, then all IPv6 addresses work fine. I can ping with them, SSH into them, etc. But if I connect the other cables, it's as if there are conflicts and I can't figure out what works correctly. But the IPv6 numbers don't work correctly anyway.
What I want:
To be able to use 3 of the 4 public IPv4 addresses I receive from the ISP on my Ubuntu server... while being able to use the approximately 10 IPv6 numbers I get through the IPv6 tunnel.
I have tried numerous versions of similar Netplan, tried to bind Interfaces to Mac addresses, but nothing works..
I've spent too many hours on this and can't find a way to solve it. Does anyone have any ideas?
My Netplan (with changed private IPs):





Netplan Configuration



network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0: 
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::1/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::2/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::3/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::4/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::5/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::6/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::7/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::8/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::9/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::10/64"
        - "2001:0a0:1c:4d2::11/64"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      routes:
        - to: "::/0"
          via: "2001:0a0:1b:4d1::1"
      ipv6-privacy: false
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4

